# how to overcome salesforce CLI slowness?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

Salesforce extensions are taking ages to load in VS-Code.

CLI team is releasing updates 5 times in a month, Not sure each release has went through  performance testing before release ?

[image]

After update I am getting following error when opening org. (after restart its fixed)

> InternalError: An internal error caused this command to fail.
> isomorphic-git error: Invalid checksum in GitIndex buffer: expected
> but saw da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709

Slowness is only for me or everyone is facing the same ?

Comment: That you are getting a git error suggests your git clone is corrupt. Try creating a second clone to see if that exhibits the same sort of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Both the CLI project and the VS-Code integration have Github repos with public issue trackers, which are monitored by the product teams:

- `cli`: [repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli) [issue tracker](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues)
- `salesforcedx-vscode`: [repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode) [issue tracker](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues)

These are great resources for issues with either project.  Searching for "isomorphic-git" in the `salesforcedx-vscode` repo shows a few recent tickets; in particular [5102](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/5102) was closed as a duplicate of `github.com/isomorphic-git` issue [1821](https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git/issues/1821) which includes a [workaround](https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git/issues/1821#issuecomment-1719597381) which may be worth trying; if it does not resolve your issue, I recommend posting your issue to the `salesforcedx-vscode` issue tracker linked above.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently two ongoing issue reported on vs-code extension.

1. [4865](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4865)
2. [4919](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4919)

Waiting for team to fix this issue.