# "sf project deploy start" hits "isomorphic-git error"

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli

Every other day I try to deploy some metadata (sf 2.11.8, PowerShell) and fail like this:

```
> sf project deploy start --metadata ApexClass:Foo
Error (1): An internal error caused this command to fail. isomorphic-git error:
Invalid checksum in GitIndex buffer: expected 656374732f456e7469746c656d656e742f666965 but saw 16929120990d33c24e3deeca6b3adce8de7e8f35
```

(Not sure, what causes this - maybe alternating use of VSCode and CLI, and VSCode leaving behind inconsistent states when deployments are cancelled.)

Adding -r as a flag doesn't make things any better. [Others got across this problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/410863/how-to-overcome-salesforce-cli-slowness) too, and there are some known issues related to it (e.g. see [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/5102) or the Github issue I created [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2439)).

```
> sf project delete tracking
```

...fails with the same error message. What is the best way to respond to this problem?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2499

Comment: Yes, I saw this too. As for the suggested workarounds: I already have the latest version of the CLI. Closing VSCode makes no difference. I'm on a source tracked Developer Sandbox, so can't recreate a Scratch org. I haven't tried undoing changes in my files though (I haven't deleted or moved anything).

Answer (score 0):

As no one comes up with a suggestion, here's what I did: logged off from the org, deleted the folder

[project]/.sf/orgs/[org ID]

and logged on. I used:

```
sf org logout
...
sf org login web --alias [choose an alias] --set-default
```

Apparently logging out and in prevents the issues described [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2439) - at least I didn't face this anymore.